# jq: how to filter by field value in array of objects?

Tags: arrays, json, select, filter, jq

having an input like this:

```
[
    {
        "foo": "aaa",
        "bar": 111
    },
    {
        "foo": "bbb",
        "bar": 111
    },
    {
        "foo": "ccc",
        "bar": 222
    },
    {
        "foo": "aaa",
        "bar": 333
    },
    {
        "foo": "ddd",
        "bar": 444
    }
]
```

i would like to select all objects with "foo" key equal to "aaa" or "bbb". so the solution is obvious:

`.[] | select ( .foo=="aaa" or .foo=="bbb"  )` 
(https://jqplay.org/s/x7FGo1uQNW)

but i would like to enhance it and replace that `x=y or x=z` to sql'ish styled `x in (y,z)`. and i got stuck, as the natural try:

`.[] | select ( .foo in (["aaa", "bbb"])  )`

results in an error:

> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:

i also tried this:

`.[] | select ( .foo | in (["aaa", "bbb"]) )`

but also not great...

> jq: error (at :21): Cannot check whether array has a string key

is this even posible?

Comment: The relevant jq filter here is `IN`, not `in`.

Comment: AFAIK, IN operator is since jq 1.6.somethig

Comment: Even if your jq does not have IN, you can still use it by first adding its `def`, which is easily found e.g. by googling.

Comment: well - sure. but i can simply do as in the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm, i managed to do it with this:

`.[] | select(.foo as $tmpvar | ["aaa", "bbb"] | index ($tmpvar ) )`

https://jqplay.org/s/g7AyRgARdU

According to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46470951/2244766
in versions above 1.5 there is a new `IN` operator that makes life a bit easier:

```
.[] | select(.foo|IN("aaa","bbb"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL-style operators don't work well for me as a straight-forward selection mechanism; I believe they have a very specific use-case, for which they are uniquely suitable for, and for anything else they're (at best) clunky. At least that's been my experience. And I haven't really figured out what that specific use-case is, either.

With all of that as a backdrop, my recommendation is to use a simple regex test:

```
map(select(.foo | test("aaa|bbb")))
```

Given the example JSON:

```
<~> $ jq . /tmp/so4229.json
[
  {
    "foo": "aaa",
    "bar": 111
  },
  {
    "foo": "bbb",
    "bar": 111
  },
  {
    "foo": "ccc",
    "bar": 222
  },
  {
    "foo": "aaa",
    "bar": 333
  },
  {
    "foo": "ddd",
    "bar": 444
  }
]
```

the above filter would result in:

```
<~> $ jq 'map(select(.foo | test("aaa|bbb")))' /tmp/so4229.json
[
  {
    "foo": "aaa",
    "bar": 111
  },
  {
    "foo": "bbb",
    "bar": 111
  },
  {
    "foo": "aaa",
    "bar": 333
  }
]
```

If you need to generate the regex based on other data within the JSON, you can do that, too:

```
. as $data | map(select(.bar==111) | .foo) | join("|") as $regex | . = $data | map(select(.foo | test($regex)))
```

which would result in:

```
<~> $ jq '. as $data | map(select(.bar==111) | .foo) | join("|") as $regex | . = $data | map(select(.foo | test($regex)))' /tmp/so4229.json
[
  {
    "foo": "aaa",
    "bar": 111
  },
  {
    "foo": "bbb",
    "bar": 111
  },
  {
    "foo": "aaa",
    "bar": 333
  }
]
```

There may be a better way to run through the JSON twice (once to get the regex values, once to use it).