# JQ checking for values in an array given as a parameter

Tags: arrays, json, jq, whitelist

I've got a simple JQ filter to update some values in an array based on the "Key", for example this is my input:

```json
[
    {
        "Key": "IDontCare",
        "Value": "something"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Tag1",
        "Value": "123-456"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Tag2",
        "Value": "121-717"
    }
]
```

I want to update both tags to a new value (same value for both), so I've got this command, that works:

```
jq --arg NEW_VALUE '987-654' \
    '[.[] |= if(.Key=="Tag1" or .Key=="Tag2") then (.Value=$NEW_VALUE) else . end]'
```

However I want to update different tags in different runs and would like to pass them as another argument. But not sure how to change the `if()` to look up the tags from the parameter.

I tried something like this but that's apparently not the right way:

```
jq --argjson TAGS '["Tag1","Tag2"]' --arg NEW_VALUE '987-654' \
    '[.[] |= if(.Key|in($TAGS)) then (.Value=$NEW_VALUE) else . end]'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IN` to see if the value is part of the list and use a much simpler update assignment using select as

```
jq --arg NEW_VALUE '987-654' --argjson TAGS '["Tag1","Tag2"]' '
   map(select( .Key | IN($TAGS[] ) ).Value |= $NEW_VALUE )' json
```

Comment: That's great! Is there a similarly concise way for JQ 1.5? It says `jq: error: IN/1 is not defined at <top-level>`

Comment: @MLu: IN is nothing but this simple function - You can use that instead - https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L274

Comment: So I changed it to `select( .Key | any($TAGS[] == .; .) )` but that still doesn't work in 1.5. The same still works in 1.6 though.

Comment: @MLu: You can adopt an approach from here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/43259563/5291015

Comment: I saw that answer before but still can't work it out. Will update our pipeline to jq 1.6, that'll be easier. I admit that jq for me is one of those magic things that I copy&paste without much understanding. I know I know...

Answer (score 2):

### With jq 1.5 or later

```
jq --arg NEW_VALUE '987-654' --argjson TAGS '["Tag1","Tag2"]' '
   def IN(s): first((s == .) // empty) // false;
   map(if .Key | IN($TAGS[]) then .Value = $NEW_VALUE else . end)
'
```

(With jq 1.6, you can obviously leave out the def of `IN/1`.)

### With jq 1.4 or later

```
jq --arg NEW_VALUE '987-654' --arg TAGS '["Tag1","Tag2"]' '
   ($TAGS|fromjson) as $TAGS
   | map(if [.Key == $TAGS[]]|any then .Value = $NEW_VALUE else . end)
'
```