# How to fix shell jq syntax to determine if JSON array contains a variable stored in a string?

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I have a JSON array output from an API, which I am interpreting with the `jq` package. I want to see if a target value exists in this array. I am quite new to shell scripting and am using one of the simpler approaches described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259563/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-array-with-jq). It works when I type the target value in manually, but not when I set it as a variable.

```
in_stock=$(jq -n --argjson v '["orange","apple","pickle"]' '$v')
echo $in_stock | jq 'contains(["pickle"])'
>>> true
echo $in_stock | jq 'contains(["spinach"])'
>>> false
favorite_food="pickle"
echo $in_stock | jq 'contains(["$favorite_food"])'
>>> false
```

I assume this is a basic syntax issue on my part. I've tried a number of variations and it outputs `false`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Always quote your variables: `echo "$in_stock"`.

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, only double quotes.

Comment: `jq "contains([\"$favorite_food\"])"`

Comment: `jq -n --argjson v '["orange","apple","pickle"]' --arg f "pickle" 'IN($v[]; $f)'`