# Using a jq expression, how to return items from a json array using an intermediate mapping array?

Tags: jq

Given this json:

```
{
  "links": [
    {
      "from": "product1",
      "to": "color1"
    },
    {
      "from": "product1",
      "to": "color2"
    },
    {
      "from": "product2",
      "to": "color3"
    }
  ],
  "hits": [
    {
      "id": "color1",
      "name": "green"
    },
    {
      "id": "color2",
      "name": "blue"
    },
    {
      "id": "color3",
      "name": "yellow"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get the color names associated to product1 (["green", "blue"]) using a jq expression?

I managed to come up with:

```
[.links[] | select(.from == "product1") | .to] as $colors | [.hits[] | select(.id == ("color1","color2")) | .name]
```

However, I don't want to hardcode ("color1","color2") but instead refer to $colors.

If I use:

```
[.links[] | select(.from == "product1") | .to] as $colors | [.hits[] | select(.id == ($colors)) | .name]
```

I get an empty array back.

Comment: You can use `IN` to test if `.id` is in `$colors[]` e.g. `select(.id | IN($colors[]))` / https://stackoverflow.com/a/43269105/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```bash
(.links | map(select(.from == "product1").to)) as $colors
| .hits | map(select(IN(.id; $colors[])).name)
```

```
[
  "green",
  "blue"
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1HDrK-YuurF)

Answer (score 2):

Build an `INDEX` from color ids to names, then select the required products and look up the color by id:

```
(INDEX(.hits[]; .id) | map_values(.name)) as $colors
| .links
| map(select(.from == "product1") | $colors[.to])
```

Or with a single JOIN + INDEX:

```
JOIN(
  INDEX(.hits[]; .id);
  .links[] | select(.from == "product1");
  .to;
  last.name)
```

Comment: There's no (explicitly articulated) guarantee that `.id` is unique within `.hits`.

Comment: Correct, but which color would you choose then? The first, the last, an arbitrary one, all of them? Given the key `id`, it's fair to assume that the identifier is unique (but not guaranteed by the data structure, you are absolutely correct on this)

Answer (score 1):

Think this does it:

```
[.links[] | select(.from == "product1") | .to] as $colors | [.hits[] | select(.id | IN($colors[])) | .name]
```