# Function IN/1 does not exist in Spring Boot Apache Camel application

Tags: apache-camel, jq

Following the clarification done in:

[Using a jq expression, how to return items from a json array using an intermediate mapping array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77100152/using-a-jq-expression-how-to-return-items-from-a-json-array-using-an-intermedia/77100192#77100192)

I have tried to implement the solution:

```
[.links[] | select(.from == "product1") | .to] as $colors | [.hits[] | select(.id | IN($colors[])) | .name]
```

However my application (Spring Boot Apache Camel) gives me this error: "Function IN/1 does not exist".

If I use "in" instead of "IN" I get: "has() is not applicable to STRING".

I am using Apache Camel 4.0.0 (with camel-jq with same version).

How to access this function or replace it by one providing the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the equivalent `select(IN($colors[]; .id))` or `select(any($colors[] == .id; .))` (this is how the filter is defined in [`builtin.jq`](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/7a72f58d2e92254652162ec7ca1b3074e3a22c35/src/builtin.jq#L277))

Or go with the `INDEX`-based solution that was also proposed under your original question :)